# Identificando número de acessos na página

Tags: php, javascript, script

Estou tentando realizar uma verificação de quantas vezes uma pessoa realiza acesso à uma determinada página, porém não sei como fazê-lo, gostaria de realizar isso em PHP ou Javascript.

Primeiro Acesso:

- Exibir instruções iniciais

Segundo Acesso:

- Exibir itens, links, ou outros elementos caso a pessoa tenha seguido as instruções no primeiro acesso. (Neste ponto, sei que serão necessárias outras validações para verificar se as instruções foram corretamente seguidas)

[...] (Outros acessos)

Comment: Olá, visto que você mesmo disse ser iniciante, sugiro começar pelo básico. Aprenda mais sobre a linguagem da qual fará uso (ou linguagens); além disso, uma boa forma é utilizando $_SESSION no PHP, pode-se criar um contador e uma verificação do valor do contador para realizar tal liberação.

Comment: Sugiro também refatorar sua pergunta para esclarecer melhor a dúvida, e indicar a linguagem que está utilizando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa utilizando PHP (visto que a linguagem a ser utilizada não foi especificada):

```php
<?php

//Iniciar a sessão
session_start();

//Verificar se a variável de contador existe (caso não exista, será criada)
if(!isset($_SESSION['visit-counter']){
    $_SESSION['visit-counter'] = 1;
}

//Toda vez que a página for recarregada, o contador receberá +1
$_SESSION['visit-counter'] += 1;

if($_SESSION['visit-counter'] <= 1){
    //Código para exibir as orientações caso o contador seja menor ou igual à 1
}else{
    //Código para exibir o link caso o contador seja maior que 1
};
```

Outras alternativas podem ser utilizar cookies, ou solicitações assíncronas com **AJAX**, mas acredito que o código acima já resolva o problema e seja o mais adequado para o caso.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta, perdoe-me pela fallta de informação...a liguagem que eu queria era em java script ou php...

Comment: adicione como resposta se ela realmente atendeu à sua dúvida :D assim outras pessoas que procurarem este tipo de informação já conseguem ver que há uma resposta aceita, e que talvez possa ajudá-las :)